# How can I dump data on the screen in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, dump

I have a query that runs and I was trying to dump the query on the screen so I can see that and paste it in my SQL server. (I used to do this in php using `var_dump()` )

I tried using `Console.Write()` in the `aspx.cs` file. But no results in the console in dev tools on the browser.

Here is my aspx button,

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="GetEmails" onclick="btnSearch_Click" />
```

Here is my function in the aspx.cs

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string query = "select * from tbl_inst";
    string queryWhere = " where time like '" + DropDownListTime.SelectedValue + "'";
    string loc= "";
    string room = "";

    if (!(loc= DropDownListLoc.SelectedValue).Equals(""))
    {
        queryWhere = " where (location1 like '" + loc + "%' or location2 like '" + loc + "%' or location3 like '" + loc + "%' or location4 like '" +
            loc + "%') and time like '" + DropDownListTime.SelectedValue + "'";
    }
    if (!(room = DropDownListRoom.SelectedValue).Equals(""))
    {
        queryWhere = " where (location1 like '" + room + "' or location2 like '" + room + "' or location3 like '" + room + "' or location4 like '" +
            room + "') and time like '" + DropDownListTime.SelectedValue + "'"; 
    }
    if (queryWhere.Contains("like ''")) { queryWhere = " where time is null"; }
    query += queryWhere; 
    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = query;
}
```

Basically I want to see the values any variables here on the screen.

```
Console.WriteLine(room);
Console.WriteLine("TEST" + queryWhere);
```

etc..

Comment: Have a look at how Tracing works: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386420(v=vs.100).aspx  and lookup sql injection

Comment: You should look into a logging library, such as [Log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To dump data to screen,( as you have asked this), you can use `Response.Write` to do that.

```
Response.Write("TEST" + queryWhere);
Response.End(); // This will stop response, so that you can get the previously written data to response
```

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty much what I was looking for.  I didn't have the response.End(). Without that, I couldn't see the data. Thanks.

Comment: Note that this will pre-maturely end the response, the rest of the code after `Response.End()` will not be processed.

Comment: Yea thats fine, Just using it for debugging. Compiler debugging doesnt work. So Im making due with this.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Debug.WriteLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline(v=vs.110).aspx) (In the System.Diagnostics namespace) to write to the debug output in Visual Studio. If you're running the web app via Visual Studio, this is sufficient.

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Hello, world");
```

If you're running it standalone in IIS on the local machine, [attach to process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s68z0b3.aspx) in order to see the debug output.

If the app is running on another computer, use the [remote debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t.aspx) in order to see the debug output.

If you want to actually get your output to be part of the HTML sent to the client, you can use `Response.Write` as Arindam suggests. But you don't have much control over where the output ends up in the DOM with that technique. So you can get really weird affects. Better to create a Literal control and append output to it.

Markup

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" id="OutputLtrl" />
```

Code Behind

```
OutputLtrl.Text += "<br />Hello, world!";
```

Comment: Not a simple solution I was looking for. I like the Response.Write(), Response.End().

Thanks.

Comment: @Nickoli I admit, it's a little simpler than what I posted. But I think if you continue to use that technique, you'll see some of the limitations. Remember to refer back to here when you hit those limitations!